# Number of Sylow 2-subgroups of a special linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

Find the number of Sylow $2$-subgroups of the special linear group of order 2 on $\mathbb{Z}$ (modulo $3$). I think it will be $1$. But I failed to prove it using the counting principle. It has $4$ sylow $3$-subgroups.

Comment: Do I have to take 1 sylow 2 subgroup & show that is normal?

Comment: What's the order of $SL(2,\Bbb Z_3)$?

Answer (score 2):

Hints: $G=SL(2,3)$ has 24 elements, hence $n_2=\#\text{Syl}_2(G) = 1$ or $=3$. If $n_2=1$, then a Sylow 2-subgroup must be normal, which is the case indeed. Show that the Sylow $2$-subgroup is isomorphic to the quaternion group $Q$ of order 8. Write down the matrices.

Comment: I know the matrices (0  -1| 1  0) & (1  1|1  -1) generate that group. But why 3 sylow 2 subgroups will not exist?

Comment: @ Nicky Hekster

Comment: You noted that there are 4 Sylow $3$-subgroups, which gives 4(3-1)=8 elements of order 3. Now if there are 3 Sylow $2$-subgroups, then they all contain the center of $SL(2,3)$ being $\{±I\}$. Then you would have 3(8-2)=18 2-elements; together with the 8 elements of order 3, this gives you 26 different elements ...

Comment: What do you mean by 2-elements. If it is elements of order 2. Then why they all are distinct?

Comment: there may be some intersection..

Comment: For a prime $p$, a $p$-element is defined to be an element of order a power of $p$. Here is another way of counting. You have $8$ elements of order $3$, and multiplying those with $-I$ gives $8$ elements of order $6$, so there can only be $8$ $2$-elements altogether, and they must make up a unique Sylow $2$-subgroup.

Comment: @user152715 Yes, there maybe an intersection, you have to rule out that as well. Did not want to give away the total solution at once. What I mean with writing down the matrices is reflected by Derek's answer.